# How to temporarily stop a task executed by thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Suppose I have a thread pool with 10 threads. Let's say that one of the threads in the pool executes some task. I want that in certain cases, the task will stop its execution, the thread will take another task and only later it will return to the previous task and continue it from where it stopped.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: It sounds like you're not using threads as threads, but making them act like thread _schedulers_ as well. It might be far easier to map tasks to threads, and keep your thread scheduling at the process level. Or find a well tested, long established java thread/task scheduling library and start using that.

Comment: This requires a lot of coordination. The task implementation needs to have some kind of checkpoint that is resumable. This is not built in to Java.

Comment: Sounds like a possible [_XY Problem_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/914217). Maybe you could say more about _why_ you want to use threads in that way.

Comment: @Solomon Slow, yes. Let's say that the task looks for a key in Redis. If it finds the key, it knows how to handle it. Otherwise, the task goes to sleep and wakes up after certain period. While the task is asleep, I want the thread to handle other tasks

Comment: What are "other tasks?" Other keys to be looked up and "handled?" I would try a slightly different architecture: I'd have a queue of tasks, and a worker thread that pulls tasks from the queue, looks up keys, and "handles" them. If the worker ever fails to find a key, then I'd have it put the task back on to the tail of the queue, and then proceed with the next task at the head of the queue. Also note: that what I just described basically is a [single-thread `Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()).

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is what coroutines do when you mix them with a threadpool dispatcher, assuming of course that you are invoking suspend functions from within the coroutine context.

When the suspend function is invoked and suspends then the thread that was occupied in the threadpool is now free to execute any other coroutine that is ready.

If you only care about using the JVM then you can use Kotlin coroutines:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html

Achieving this in a pure Java environment might be possible using one of these coroutine frameworks for Java:

- https://github.com/offbynull/coroutines
- https://github.com/esoco/coroutines
- https://github.com/rendaw/java-coroutines
- forthcoming Java fibers: https://openjdk.java.net/projects/loom/